# P-value of a One-sided One-sample t Test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

John claims that the typical lifetime of a car in his shop with 10 years warranty, is significantly more than 10 years. To test the claim, 9 cars are randomly selected, with lifetimes recorded. Sample mean lifetime is 13.5 years, and sample standard deviation is 3.2 years. Assuming the lifetime has a normal distribution, what conclusion can be drawn at 1% significant level?

So I have several tables and formulas here, first I am looking to see if it's a one sample or two sample problem, it's one sample. Then I am looking to see of the sample is large or small, it's small, only 9. Then I am looking to see if the population variance or standard deviation is known, or unknown, and it's unknown. And lastly I am looking for normality, and it's normally distributed. So with this information, I'd assume we're using the T test looking for the mue (population mean) parameter.

Which then follows:

$H_0: \mu = 10$

$H_a: \mu > 10$

$T = (\bar X - \mu)/(S/\sqrt{n})$

Plugging our values in, I get 3.281 as a T-score.

The rejection region is then defined by $T > T_\alpha(\nu)$ where $\nu = n - 1.$

So on the T-table, with degrees 8, and an alpha of .01, this would be the same as the $T > -T_1-\alpha$ so alpha would be now .99, and we can find the T-score of .99 from the table ensuring to make it negative as -2.896.

Our P-value would also be $P(T > 3.281).$

Now since our test statistic which is 3.281, is greater than -2.896, it's in the rejection region and we can reject the null hypothesis. Which in turn then, we can also support John's claim. So if I did all this correct, great, but the options I am given for this problem are the following:

a. Sufficient evidence at 1% to support the claim, and the p-value is equal to P(T > 3.355).

b. Sufficient evidence at 1% to reject the claim, and the p-value is equal to P(T < -3.281).

c. Insufficient evidence at 1% to support the claim, and the p-value is equal to P(Z > 2.896).

d. Insufficient evidence at 1% to support the claim, and the p-value is equal to P(Z > 2.896).

e. None of these answers

Is the answer here really e? Did I do everything correct? Already seems kind of a funky question as one answer is repeated and we're not even using Z. And the answer could be a. but that t-score is if the alpha level was 0.005, and we have an alpha of 0.01, and it's not a two tail test, it's a one tail test. And then b. is wrong because it's not negative nor <.

Comment: Answer A would only make sense to me if it was a two-tail test, as we'd then be dividing the alpha by 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **one-sample test** because you are comparing results
of your sample of size $n = 9$ against a hypothetical value
(the 10 year warranty length).

It is a **t test** because the population is assumed to be normal and
the population SD $\sigma$ is unknown (estimated by $S$). 
[Correctly understood, such a test is a t test (not a z test)
whenever $\sigma$ is unknown, *regardless* of the sample size.]

Thus, as you say, you are testing the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 10$ 
against the one-sided alternative $H_a: \mu > 10.$ The test statistic
is
$$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{13.5 - 10}{3.2/\sqrt{9}}
= 3.281.$$

Under $H_0$ (jargon for 'assuming the null hypothesis to be true),
$T \sim \mathsf{T}(8),$ Student's t distribution with degrees of
freedom $n - 1 = 9 - 1 = 8.$

Working at the fixed significance level $\alpha = .01 = 1\%,$ we reject
$H_0$ when $T \ge t^* = 2.896,$ where $t^*$ cuts probability 0.01 from
the upper tail of $T \sim \mathsf{T}(8).$  You can find $t^* = 2.896$ on
the row of a printed t table marked `DF = 8` or by using software. (The
computation from R statistical software is shown below.) Because
$T = 3.281 > t^* = 2.896$ you reject $H_0$ at the 1% level.

```
qt(.99, 8)
## 2.896459
```

Generally speaking, you can't find the exact P-value of a t test from
printed tables because a table gives you only a few probabilities.
Using software, you can find the P-value in this problem as 
$P(T > 3.281) = 0.0056.$ So you could reject at the 5% level, the 1% level,
or even the 0.6% level, but *not* at the 0.5% level.

```
1 - pt(3.281, 8)
## 0.005585558
```

Thus P-values have become popular only in the computer age. Their advantage
is that each person can test at their own significance level $\alpha$ one
the P-value is known. In the t table in my book the t-values that bracket
3.281 are 2.896 at tail probability 0.01 and 3.355 at tail probability 0.005,,
so all I can say about the P-value from looking at this table is that
the P-value is between 0.01 and 0.005.

The figure below shows the density function ot $\mathsf{T}(8).$ The vertical
blue line is the observed value T = 3.281, and the area under the curve to
the right of it is 0.00556. The dotted vertical red line at 2.896 cuts 1%
of the probability from the upper tail of this distribution.

[image]

*Note:* As far as your multiple choice questions is concerned, it may be a trick
question. Note that $P(T > 3.281) = P(T < - 3.281)$ if you're thinking
of the symmetrical random variable $T \sim \mathsf{T}(8)$. But it is strange
to write $P(T < - 3.281),$ if you're thinking of $T$ as the observed
value of the t statistic. This is one reason I'm not a fan of multiple-choice
tests. (Contrary to student lore, there are times when 'none of the above'
is the best answer. Not sure if this is one of them.)

Comment: Thank you for yet another superb answer, really helped me understand a lot more than I had asked. I guess the t-value does not turn negative then as I had originally understood, I guess it just means that they are equal T with alpha .99 and T with alpha .01. Which would make sense since it is symmetrical.

Comment: After you Accepted, I extended my note at the end about the multiple choice question.